# Como inserir dados em um B.D MySQL com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Este aqui é o formulário para inserir dados

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="cadastrando.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="nome"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="idade"><br><br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"> Masculino
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"> Feminino<br>
        <input type="text" name="email">
        <input type="password" name="senha"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="peso"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="altura"><br>
        <input type="text" name="qntd_exe">
        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

E este aqui é o leitor de dados com o comando para inserir os dados

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tcc");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
<?php

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$idade = $_POST['idade'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$peso = $_POST['peso'];
$altura = $_POST['altura'];
$imc = ($peso/($altura*$altura));
$qntd_exe = $_POST['qntd_exe'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO usuario VALUES ";
$sql .= "($nome', '$idade', '$email', '$senha', '$peso', '$altura', '$imc', '$qntd_exe', '$sexo')"; 
mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
mysqli_close($link);
echo "Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Por mais que eu pesquise e mude vários códigos ele não aparece erro, mas também não insere os dados no B.D

Comment: Se você não definir os nomes das colunas na cláusula `insert`, você precisa definir o valor de todas elas, incluindo o `id`.

Comment: Segue um exemplo simples: https://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Formul%C3%A1rio_PHP_%2B_Mysql

Embora não seja com as melhores práticas, pode dar uma clareada na tua mente.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, muito obrigado!

Comment: Ah, mas se o id é auto increament como eu deixo na hora de inserir? vazio?

Comment: Se não especificar os nomes das colunas, precisa sim. Neste caso, basta colocar o valor como `default`.

Comment: não precisa colocar o id me referindo a query por mim sugerida  INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando esta parte do seu código:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$idade = $_POST['idade'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$peso = $_POST['peso'];
$altura = $_POST['altura'];
$imc = ($peso/($altura*$altura));
$qntd_exe = $_POST['qntd_exe'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO usuario VALUES ";
$sql .= "($nome', '$idade', '$email', '$senha', '$peso', '$altura', '$imc', '$qntd_exe', '$sexo')"; 
mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
mysqli_close($link);
```

Se você não especificar os nomes das colunas que serão inseridos valores, você deve, obrigatoriamente, fornecer o valor de todas elas. Como você não definiu, você obrigatoriamente deve fornecer o valor da coluna `id`, considerando que é a única ausente. Supondo que ela seja `auto increment`, basta definir o valor da mesma como `DEFAULT`:

```
INSERT INTO usuario VALUES (DEFAULT, ...);
```

Outra erro é a falta de uma aspa simples no valor do nome:

```
    $sql .= "($nome', '$idade', ...
    //        ^---- Aqui deveria ter uma aspa simples
```

Finalmente, o último valor que deveria ser inserido é o sexo:

```
$sql .= "(..., '$imc', '$qntd_exe', '$sexo')";
//                                   ^--- Valor de sexo
```

Porém a variável `$sexo` não é definida no programa. Julgando pelo seu formulário, acredito que tenha faltado algo como:

```
$sexo = $_POST["sex"];
```